# How to initialize recurring `std::unordered_map` via curly braces

Tags: c++, initialization, curly-braces

I need to initialize a type implementing tree-like structure.

```
Tree t1 = 1;
Tree t2 = {{"a",t1},{"b",{{"x",2},{"y",4}}},{"c",5}};
```

So i defined structure which inherits from std::unordered_map. I had to wrap recurring `Tree` in smart pointer.

```
//tree.h
    using std;
    struct Tree : unordered_map<string, unique_ptr<Tree>>{
        int simple;
    
        Tree() = default;
        Tree(unsigned s): simple{s}{};
        Tree(const initializer_list<pair<string, unique_ptr<Tree>>> & il): simple{s} {
            // does not compile, would not work anyway 'coz the pointer
        }
    };
```

I can't figure out how to specify the initializer list.

there is something that might help:

```
struct TreeV : vector<pair<string, TreeV>>{
...
TreeV(const vector<pair<string, TreeV>> & v) : vector<pair<string, TreeV>>(v){};
}
vector<pair<string, TreeV>> t3 = {{"a",t1},{"b",{{"x",2},{"y",4}}},{"c",5}};
```

How can I catch recurrent curly braces structure in the 'initializer_list'?
or
How can I initialize recurring pattern of std::unordered_map from curly braces structure?

Comment: *"How can I initialize recurring pattern of std::unordered_map from curly braces structure?"* -- don't forget that there is a `unique_ptr` to initialize, in addition to the maps.

Comment: Your example has multiple other errors that causes it to not compile as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the reference from the initializer list. You cannot pass rvalues while using non const references. Also remove the `simple{s}` from the member initializer list if `s` isn't even defined anywhere.

```
Tree(std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Tree>>> il) {};
```

Then something like this would compile.

```
Tree t = { 
  { "one", std::make_unique<Tree>() },
  { "two", std::unique_ptr<Tree>(new Tree({ // unique_ptr is used here because make_unique does not support initializer lists.
    {
      "three", std::make_unique<Tree>()
    }}))
  }
};
```

But I would question the use of `unique_ptr` altogether, is there a particular reason for using them here? I assume the memory would be managed by the unordered_map anyways? Here's how it would look without the use of `unique_ptr`:

```
// This would allow to use syntax that resembles your goal
Tree(std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::string, Tree>> il) {};
...
Tree t = { 
  { "one", {} },
  { "two", {
      { "three", {} }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: `simple` is member variable of `Tree`. Use of `unique_ptr` (o something similar) is needed as without it template `unordered_map` would have to be instantiated with incomplete type, which it can't.  The proposed constructor compiles happily.

Comment: As soon as i want to iterate through `il` in `Tree(std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::string, Tree>> il)` i get error message "use of deleted function from std::pair.

Comment: `unique_ptr` can't be copied use `shared_ptr`. 
`Tree(unsigned s): simple{s}{};` a common mistake is to put an unnecessary superfluous semicolon after a function. `struct Tree ... }` a actual error is to miss one off the end of a struct by the way.